# Tikz: Scope with local coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made a page with a coordinate system (shown in red) with (0,0) at the top left corner of the page and coordinates increasing towards the bottom right of the page.

Now I would like to set up a rotated scope (shown in green) for the right half of the page, like this:

[image: layout]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperheight=17cm,paperwidth=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={draw, rectangle},
        remember picture, overlay,
        shift={(current page.north west)},yscale=-1 % (0,0) at the top left corner
    ]

        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south)},rotate=90,transform shape]
        \begin{scope}[xscale=-1,yscale=-1]
        \node at (0,0){B};
        \node at (1,1){F};
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But whenever I got the direction of the coordinates right, the contents is mirrored:

[image: screenshot]

It's like the inner scope inherits the "transform shape" of the outer scope or something.

Comment: This is because of `transform shape`, which subjects the shapes to the transformations `xscale=-1,yscale=-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the inner scopes inherit the keys from the ambient scopes. This is the main reason why nesting `tikzpicture`s is a problem. You may use `transform shape=false` in the inner scope.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperheight=17cm,paperwidth=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={draw, rectangle},
        remember picture, overlay,
        shift={(current page.north west)},yscale=-1 % (0,0) at the top left corner
    ]

        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south)},rotate=90,transform shape]
        \begin{scope}[xscale=-1,yscale=-1,transform shape=false]
        \node at (0,0){B};
        \node at (1,1){F};
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then the rotation is gone, too. The node should still be rotated.

Comment: @AndreKR Well, how would I know? You can add `nodes={rotate=90}`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the issue:

`transform shape` is a property of the node, not a property of the scope, so there is no way to say "apply the `rotate` to the nodes, but not the `xscale`".

However, `xscale` and `yscale` are not necessary to set up a local coordinate system. I'm not sure why I used them in the first place, but `x` and `y` work just as well, and because they are not *transformations* they do not distort the contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperheight=17cm,paperwidth=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={draw, rectangle},
        remember picture, overlay,
        shift={(current page.north west)},y=-1cm % (0,0) at the top left corner
    ]

        \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south)},rotate=90,transform shape]
        \node at (0,0){B};
        \node at (1,1){F};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]